# Update CHANGELOG.md using fastlane

Tags: fastlane

I want to create lane which prompt user to provider changelog and then save it in CHANGELOG.MD file using CHANGELOG.MD file guidelines (sections with build number, subsections: Add, Remove, etc). Is it possible to update CHANGELOG.md file using fastlane? How?

#### Edit

I am Fastlane newbie and I looking for a help. I googled a little bit but I didn't find any helpful information. Could someone tell me which plugin/lane do you use and show me an example of usage? When I asked this questions I wanted to find out the best practices about handling updating CHANGELOG.md file via Fastlane.

Comment: There are several plugins for that, just use Google.

Comment: I edited my questions. Thanks for response :)